# How to find out if input is valid without form in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, validation, input

I've faced following issue:
I have a `<table>`, where `<tr>`'s a generated via `ng-repeat`, and each `<tr>` contains several `<input>` elements. Smth like this:

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="plan in plans">
    <td>
      <input ng-pattern="/^\d+((\.|\,)\d+)?$/" ng-model="plan.field1" ng-blur="updateRow(plan)">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input ng-pattern="/^\d+((\.|\,)\d+)?$/" ng-model="plan.field2" ng-blur="updateRow(plan)">
    </td>    
  </tr>
</table>
```

When user finishes editing input I want to update full row. But I want to do it only if this input is valid. I mean I want to execute `updateRow(plan)` only if this condition `ng-pattern="/^\d+((\.|\,)\d+)?$/"` is satisfied. Or maybe somehow check it within `updateRow()`. But I can't find a way to do it without forms.

1)Is there a way to do it? Or may be there is better way to implement my idea?
2)And also is there way to bind  ng-blur to each input in a row? Because I have about 20 inputs in a row and it looks bad when there is such amount of repeating.

Thanks to everybody in advance!

Comment: I guess, you could check input validity on some event (for instance on keyup) and then if validation is passed you can fire updateRow()

Answer (score 0):

So I solved the first question by using forms and `ng-form`. I put every `tr` element in separate `tbody` and applied `ng-form` to each `tbody` element.
So i believe that I have to use forms if I need validation.